# Python Tkinter: How to use update() thread safe instead of using mainloop()?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

For context why I want to use update() and update_idletask() instead of just using mainloop():
**I need to display a cv2.imshow fullscreen FullHD 50 FPS stream, grabbed in a different thread from a Basler Dart USB camera, with a (Tkinter) GUI window topmost .**

The conversion from the cv2 Mat to a tk PhotoImage and updating the canvas or label displaying the image is taking over 30ms under best conditions, while grabbing the frame and performing some bitwise operations to overlay an transparent image only takes a few ms. Displaying the stream this way is to slow.

For the sake of not needing to learn another gui framework right now and reusing most of the existing code I found a solution to displaying a cv2.imshow() fullscreen window and simultaneously a tk.Tk window topmost, but I am unsure if this is a good idea and how to implement it the right way, because of the warning in cpython _tkinter.c about the thread lock situation.

I read some suggested solutions for displaying a tk and cv2 window at the same time by using threading, but those didn't work for me, maybe because the image grabbing within my CV2Window is already in a thread.

**Just calling update() within the cv2 loop works easy, but I don't know if this is a good idea**:
Would it be safe not caring about the tcl lock and just using update(), if I implement the communication between the two windows with a threadsafe queue and nothing within the tkinter events blocks too long?

My simplified code right now is:

```
# Standard library imports
from cv2 import waitKey
from sys import exit

# Local application imports
from CV2Window import CV2Window
from tkWindows import MenuWindow, MenuFrame

# child class of tk.Tk
# -topmost and overrideredirect True, geometry "+0+0"
class MenuApp(MenuWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # frame withdraws and deiconifies buttons when the menu toggle button is clicked,
        # to create a dropdown-menu. Row 0 is used by the toggle button
        self.menu_frame = MenuFrame(self)
        self.menu_frame.add_button("Example Button", command=None, icon="file-plus", row=1)
        self.menu_frame.add_button("Close", command=self.close, icon="power", row=2)

        self.menu_frame.grid()

    def close(self):
        self.destroy()


def main():
    cv2window = CV2Window()
    gui = MenuApp()

    while True:
        ## Update cv2 window
        cv2window.update()
        
        ## Update GUI manually
        gui.update()
        
        ## Check if GUI is still open, otherwise close cv2 window
        try:
            gui.winfo_exists()
        except:
            print("GUI closed, closing cv2 window..")
            cv2window.close()
            break
```

But the CV2Window contains the camera grabbing with MyCameraHandler, which is a class version of the Basler pypylon example "[grabusinggrabloopthread.py](https://github.com/basler/pypylon/blob/master/samples/grabusinggrabloopthread.py)" and is aquiring the frames in a different thread.

Simplified code for CV2Window:

```
# Standard library imports
from cv2 import namedWindow, setWindowProperty, imshow, WINDOW_FULLSCREEN, WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, waitKey, destroyAllWindows
from pypylon.genicam import GenericException

# Local application imports
from CameraClass import MyCameraHandler

class CV2Window():
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.cam_handler = MyCameraHandler()
            self.cam_handler.start_grabbing()
        except GenericException as e:
            print("Exception in CV2Window: ", e)
            try:
                self.cam_handler.stop()
            except:
                pass
            exit(1)

        self.img = self.cam_handler.get_image()
        namedWindow("cam", WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
        setWindowProperty("cam", WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        imshow("cam", self.img)

    def update(self):
        self.img = self.cam_handler.get_image()
        waitKey(0)
        imshow("cam", self.img)

    def close(self):
        destroyAllWindows()
        self.cam_handler.stop()
```

By reading the cpython *_tkinter.c* code this could be a problem:

> The threading situation is complicated.  Tcl is not thread-safe, except
> when configured with --enable-threads.
> So we need to use a lock around all uses of Tcl.  Previously, the
> Python interpreter lock was used for this.  However, this causes
> problems when other Python threads need to run while Tcl is blocked
> waiting for events.

If mainloop() is used, Tkinter will get and release the right locks at the right time, but then it is not possible to display and update my CV2Window. From my understanding, update() is only a single tcl call, without any lock management.

As of right now, it is working, but there is zero communication between the two windows.
I need to be able to invoke methods in CV2Window from the Tkinter GUI, and probably in the future also sharing small data/information from the CV2Window to Tkinter.

The next thing I'll try is communicating with a queue, since I don't need to share the image, only some information or actions to perform, and the queue.Queue is threadsafe... this should work, I think?

As long as the events performed because of the update call are taking less than ~15ms, I should be fine and get my needed frametime of <20ms together with the frame grab and imshow, right?

Am I missing something? I am quite new to Python and Tkinter, and wrapping my head around the tcl stuff invoked by Tkinter isn't that easy for me, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that Tk uses thread-specific data internally for a whole bunch of things, including memory management, so that in most scenarios it can avoid global locks. If you're on Unix, you can get the ID of a widget's drawing surface and then *maybe* tell the other component to use that?

Comment: If I want to display the stream with a widget I need to convert the cv2 Mat image to a photo displayable by Tkinter and this is taking too long, I can not accomplish 20ms frametime for 50 FPS if converting to a PhotoImage and displaying it takes 40ms, even if it would be threaded.
The PCs for the application are running Windows 10.

With my code right now I have 50 FPS for the stream and 30 FPS for the GUI with ~10% cpu (4 cores). Old Code with everything in Tkinter is 25% cpu, one core fully used, and only about 15 FPS.

Comment: Photo images are absolutely not designed for video; their design goal was supporting full colour images (and in particular doing so on displays that used a 256-colour palette, a technique that's fortunately now long gone). A custom image type would seem to be a better idea, or maybe even a custom widget. Trouble is, this is all right at the edge of what I know about.

Comment: Thats what I found out after trying. Hence the idea to display the image outside of tk, but keeping tk as a GUI overlay. Honestly I think implementing a new image type or something like that is out of the scope with my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are on Unix**, the `winfo_id()` method of any Tkinter widget will return the XID of the underlying drawing surface. You can use that handle to get some other code to draw on that surface. You are recommended to use a `Frame` with the background set to either `None` or the empty string (not quite sure which works!) so that Tkinter won't draw on it at the same time; no other widget class supports that. (I know I'd use an empty string in Tk for that effect, which gets converted into a NULL in the underlying structure and that triggers the frame painting code to do nothing on a redraw/repaint request.) I don't know how you'd get the XID into the other framework; it would be responsible for opening its own connection and setting up listeners, but that would work very well in another thread (or even another process; I've done that in the past). **That solution does not work on other platforms**, as I believe they use IDs that do not have meaning outside of the toolkit implementation. (Technically, there are a few options in Tk that Tkinter does not expose that would help, *possibly,* but I'm not sure. The `-container`/`-use` protocol is not well documented.)

More generally, a custom image type (pretty much requires writing C or C++ code) would let you do something close, though the whole image system is not really designed for animated streaming media. (It certainly isn't designed for hardware acceleration!) It's not something for a quick fix, and I've never tried doing that myself.

Comment: I'm using windows. For now, I'll continue using the posted method of displaying an OpenCV fullscreen image and topmost the tk gui, no problems so far.

Comment: But actually it is possible to use a Frame with an empty string to display OpenGL content I found out. Should work on all systems. For python there is even a package called [pyopengltk](https://github.com/jonwright/pyopengltk)
If I have some time left, I'll look further into this, seems promising.